# Insight behind DCT-III (Type 3)

Tags: dft, dct

Following the sketch from Wikipedia [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform#/media/File:DCT-symmetries.svg), I am able to carry out DCT-II with DFT by manipulating the input signal:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import fftpack as fftpack
from numpy import fft as fft
n = 5
x = 3 + np.arange(n) #my input signal
xpad = np.zeros(2 * n)
xpad[0:n] = x[:]
xpad[n:] = x[::-1]
X = fftpack.dct(x)
tmp = fft.rfft(xpad) * np.exp(-0.5j * 2 * np.pi / (2 * n) * np.arange(1 + n))
Xpad = np.real(tmp[0:n])
```

X and Xpad are in very close numerical agreement. Trickery is limited to how to come up with an output signal of n real-valued entries from a temporary result of n + 1 complex-valued entries. The issue is addressed by a spectral interpolation to shift the signal by half sample. This makes the imaginary part of the spectrum to be zero everywhere. The n + 1 vs n is a non-issue as the mirroring notches exactly the highest frequency.

I seem unable to reason about the signal manipulations required to implement a DCT-III with a DFT: after the special mirroring of the input signal, a DFT is carried out... then what?

```
 xpad[0:n] = x[:]
 xpad[n] = 0
 xpad[n + 1:] = -x[n - 2::-1]
 Y = fft.rfft(xpad)
```

I am aware that DCT-III is the transposed version of DCT-II (i.e. reversing the steps of DCT-II, would indeed provide a DCT-III implementation, IDFT-based), but that is not the point. It does not take direct consideration about the even/odd symmetries as implied by the Wikipedia sketch.